# What is _xclick-merchant?

Tags: paypal

What does _xclick-merchant means in terms of PayPal? iTunes buttons use it, but if I try to substitute any other PayPal email in it'll just say that it doesn't even exist. Is there any documentation if I wanted to try to implement it myself?

Answer (score 1):

_xclick-merchant means in paypal terms that which merchant id is registered with the api key provided by the paypal at the time of merchant account creation. Api key is unique for every merchant account and if you change with any other email it will not be found because paypal in his end checks for both api key and provided paypal email if matches payment screen appear other wise error which you are getting.you can get all your required information here
https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: What API key?

From PayPal's developer page it seems as if _xclick-merchant isn't even valid. http://puu.sh/5wRvx/1c7d381f63.png

This is iTunes link: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=paypalgroup%40group.apple.com&mp_max=500&cmd=_xclick-merchant

If you edited their email with your own, though, it'll simply redirect you away. Why?